# Android overflow menu API level 24

Tags: android, android-studio, android-7.0-nougat, overflow-menu

Is there any behavior changes in connection with overflow menus in API level 24? It seems menus now draw submenus near the main menu (if there is enough space). Am I wrong? And some menus (with submenus) invoke crashes on my emulators. Here is an example of my menu's xml:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com. ... .MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/sub_menu1"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Submenu"
        app:showAsAction="never">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings11"
                android:orderInCategory="110"
                android:title="Item11"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings12"
                android:orderInCategory="120"
                android:title="Item12"
                app:showAsAction="never" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Item2"
        android:orderInCategory="200"
        android:title="Item2"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>
</menu>
```

**Update1:** Here's the [link](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=221921) to the Issue Tracker and an interesting comment that describes how to prevent crashes on emulators:

> #8 ... It seems like enabling under "developer settings" the option of "show layout bounds" prevents the crash.

**Update2:** It seems now works fine on API level 25.